# UILocalNotification to open detail view controller for a specific item

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'd like to set alerts for specific items and have a `UILocalNotification` open a specific item from my table view controller and display its details. In other words, when a notification appears I'd like to be able to tap on "Show item" and instead of showing the list of all items I'd like to see the details of just that specific item.

For this to work I would need to store information on the specific item (title, index, etc.) How can I do this? Store the title of my item in `UILocalNotification.userInfo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add information

Objective c

```
localNotification.userInfo =@{@"title":title,@"index":index};
```

Swift

```
var userInfo = [String:String]()
userInfo["title"] = title
userInfo["index"] = index
notification.userInfo = userInfo
```

To get information when notification arrive

Objective C

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@“title = %@”,notification.userInfo[@"title"]);
    NSLog(@“index = %@”,notification.userInfo[@"index"]);
}
```

Swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification!) {
    println(notification.userInfo?["title"])
    println(notification.userInfo?["index"])
}
```

********EDIT********

**Passing the "title" and "index"  from the notification's userInfo to the `Table View Controller`**

Objective C

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BookNotification" object:notification.userInfo]
    // or update table view data source
}
```

Swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification!) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("BookNotification", object:notification.userInfo)
    // or update table view data source
}
```

In `Table View Controller` add observer in when notification arrive get "title" and "index" then update `Table View Controller` `datasource` and reload `tableview`

Inside  `Table View Controller`
Objective C

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveBookNotification:) 
    name:@"BookNotification"
    object:nil];


- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{ 
    NSString *title = notification.userInfo[@"title"];
    NSString *title = notification.userInfo[@"index"];
    // Update data source and reload
}
```

Swift

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receiveBookNotification:", name:"BookNotification", object: nil)


func receiveTestNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let title = notification.userInfo?["title"]
    let index = notification.userInfo?["index"]
    // Update data source and reload
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When I want to get information when the notification arrives, I'd like to pass the title from the notification's userInfo to the Table View Controller. How do I do this? Making the title a global variable? What's the best practice?

Comment: Answer updated to reflect "pass the title from the notification's userInfo to the Table View Controller"

Comment: Thanks! I tried this. Added to viewDidLoad() the following:         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(RemindersMainVC.receiveReminderNotification), name:"ReminderNotification", object: nil). Everything works, receiveTestNotification() does get called, however the notification argument is nil.

Comment: Fixed it. Needs to be: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("BookNotification", object: nil, userInfo: notification.userInfo)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do that. The local notification's userInfo property is intended for passing any information you need to your notification handler.

You're going to need to add actions to your local notifications if you want a button to appear to the user, and you will also have to handle the case where the notification fires while your app is in the foreground and no notice is displayed to the user.

Comment: Looks fine, you can do this.!

Comment: It's called "deeplinking" if you ever search on Google :-)

Comment: The examples on the net seem to suggest that userInfo is a dictionary. Is that the case? Typically what keys would be used in such cases?

Comment: Yes, Apple's frameworks type it as a dictionary. It's for you, so you can use whatever keys/values you want. I've seen people pass other object types in the userInfo parameter before, but I'd suggest sticking with a dictionary. It's a wrapper that can contain any number of key/value pairs containing whatever you want it to.